# parametrized query in excel 2010 cell

Tags: sql-server, excel

i would like to make a formula in excel that querys my microsoft sql server 2005 database

something like:

= select count(*) as 'aantal bezoeknummers'
from bezwe 
where z03 between **A2** and **B2**
and z02 = **C1**;

the bold referers should be the parameters given in the excel file

my previous tries:
i went to: data>from other sources>from MS query>MS access database.

after a long search to the location of my database on the server i found out that the extension is .MDF
the MS query tool only works with .MDB and .ACCDB

other searches on the net or on this forum didn't helped me out with a proper understandable solution

if there is any solution possible i would be please with your help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the query via Import from Other Sources, MS SQL Server. In the query, enter `?` for each parameter you want to take from a cell. Excel should then automatically ask for the parameters, and you can link to your cells. See http://snippetsandhelp.blogspot.de/2013/05/excel-2013-getting-data-from.html?m=1 or one of the various articles when searching for "excel query parameters".